# Migrating a large-scale application from JavaEE to Akka

Tags: java, scala, jakarta-ee, web-applications, akka

Suppose I have a very large-scale server-side web application written in JavaEE (and related technologies classically combined with it), and I decided to migrate it completely to Akka (and related technologies usually combined with it, including moving the code to Scala). The reasons of the migration decision are not important: suppose I have to do it, and that's all to it.

My question is: What would be the strategy to follow here, aiming to optimize the migration time and the scalability of the resulting application?

If the question lacks of details, I can provide some, although I would like to hear strategies without being very specific.

Answer (score 2):

This is an open ended question. But let me try and give you some ideas. Having worked with both J2EE as well as Play2/Akka/Spray.io (Scala) based system I can provide you will the following high level/general guidance for migration.

**Partition your system:** Partition your current system based on functionality and rank them according to their criticality to business, your stakeholders and clients. Partitions can done based on different dimensions ( architectural components at runtime, business features, development team/modules) etc. You also need to find dependencies between these partitions.

**Identify candidate partition:** Once you have ranked partitions, it’s useful to pick the smallest possible partition that overlaps in as many dimensions as possible and has the least amount of coupling. Usually this is the case if your initial architecture is modular.

**Implement a prototype:** Take the candidate partition and create a prototype that provides the same functional capability. Now evaluate and compare the new capability against the old in terms of various quality attributes (performance, modifiability, extensibility etc). The prototype will also give you an estimate of technical risk, challenges, and effort.

**Create a new architecture:** I think at this point you should have enough input to create the first version of your new architecture. Also identify how capabilities of other partitions will be implemented in this new architecture. Selecting the most complex partition and try to map it to this new architecture is really good exercise and can massively reduce your technical risk in the future.

**Field the prototype:** Try to field the prototype to a small subset of users/stakeholders and get feedback. Decoupling the prototype using REST/pub-sub interfaces is a good idea.

**Plan for migration:** Create a plan and schedule for rest of your system.

I can be more specific if you provide more targeted questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply)) I understand, but it would be very nice if you provide some more "real" stuff about the steps you mention above. For example, take any well-known application as example and give a rough description of the steps above applied to this application. With this, I will accept your answer.